# How to mock a class created inside the tested class?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

In the PHPUnit documentation, the section dealing with mocks explain how to attach a mock object inside the tested class :

```php
...
$observer = $this->getMockBuilder('Observer')
                 ->setMethods(array('update'))
                 ->getMock();
...
$subject = new Subject('My subject');
$subject->attach($observer);
$subject->doSomething();
```

In my case, I want to test a `Subject` method. This method create many objects like this:

```php
public function myMethod() {
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $this->collection []= new Observer(/* some data */);
    }
}
```

How can I mock all of the Observers?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock the class.  The `new` operator will get the definition of the class based on your autoloader or what it is memory already.  You can't dynamically replace the class definition in your test.

You could create an alternate class definition for `Observer` that would have defined behaviors and would in essence be a "mock" class that you would use.  The problem with this is that if you run this test with the tests for the actual `Observer` class, you will end up with an error that you cannot redefine the class.  And things get really complicated.

Your example is pretty simplistic but I would verify it by making sure that all the elements in `Subject::collection` are instances of `Observer`.  If there was any specific data that I knew about each observer then I would use actual `Observer` methods to verify them.  (This isn't a good practice though).

If your method is creating the objects and then calling methods on them, I would seriously reconsider your design.  I would break up `myMethod` into at least two methods.  One that attaches an `Observer` object that you can use in your test to pass a mock object in with.  And the other that calls the methods of the `Observer` which would be the rest of the `myMethod` function that you don't have.

Comment: I had come to this conclusion but I don't want to create many attach() methods in many classes. In fact, I don't want to adapt my code to unit-testing tools.

Comment: You shouldn't need to.  You could use either an abstract base class or a trait to specify an attach() method.
Moving the new operator out of the class isn't adapting your code to a unit-testing tool.  It is following a good design practice.  When I instantiate an instance of Subject, I may not know that Observer is coming along.  Observer may relay on an external system that in my particular use case I don't want to use.  Or I may want to change which Observer is being used in my use case.  Because of the new operator, I have to use Observer and have no choice.  The design is less flexible.

Comment: Ok I understand. My problem is that I use FuelPHP and all classes are already loaded when I'm calling PhpUnit. So "Observer" is already there.

Comment: I am not sure you completely understand.  The problem isn't with loading of the classes, but with reusing/modifying your code.  There is also the issue of being explicit of what your class needs and is using.  If in the future, you want to change Subject or add a different Observer in certain scenarios, it will be more difficult.

Comment: I don't think things like ```new Observer(...)``` inside loops are bad design. For example, in a controller, we can use many classes declarations and we will not create an ```attach()``` system for each.